# Protecting a new file format?

Tags: applications

I'm wondering when you create a new file format, what are the options to protect said format from being used without consent? I don't think you can patent a file format based off what I have read so far. So not sure if anyone has any idea on this.

I know this might seem like a weird question given that file formats are used by anyone and everyone. But if I was to create a file format that acted as an application in a sense how would I protect this?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? What's your goal? If this were possible, it would be used for DRM, of course, so I am pretty sure you can't protect it.

Comment: I have an idea that if I could get it to work would revolutionize copyright protection. But I would obviously not want another company or individual using the file format that were not licensed to do so. The thing about it would be that although it would be file format, inside of this format would be built in applications that would do something. Again I don't know if it's possible to do this but if I could I would want to protect my idea.

Comment: "Inside of this format would be built in applications"- it sounds like your format is either a virus or an enormous security hole

Comment: You want to protect a digital artifact from being used "without consent". Computers **don't understand** consent, so this is impossible. All you can create are *technical* hurdles, which apply to all users, legit or not.

Comment: You could encrypt the contents and then only give the decryption key to people you trust (or people you allow to use the data)

Comment: +1 for Brandin. Throw in a bit of DRM, and it might qualify for some of the DMCA protections. There is a reason why DRM is the vogue nowadays, because the DMCA clause offered impenetrable protection to things it was never thought to protect. (IANAL; this is not a legal advice.)

Answer (score 5):

You really can't.

If you make the file format sufficiently painful to deal with and avoid providing documentation for the actual file format, you can make the logical choice for the vast majority of people to use your API to interact with the file.  Nothing prevents someone from going to the effort of reverse engineering the file format and interacting with raw files themselves but if it's much easier to use your API, that's the path most people will take.  And if you release new versions constantly that make subtle tweaks that break existing code that isn't using your API, you can ratchet up the pain anyone would have dealing with your raw files directly.

This is basically (intentionally and unintentionally) the path Microsoft walked with the various binary Office file formats.  They were sufficiently complex that if a competing office suite tried to read or write anything more than the simplest file, you'd inevitably find that something was lost in translation.

Of course, if you do something like this, particularly intentionally, you'll incur the wrath of a large fraction of developers.  In the vast, vast majority of cases, if you're creating a file format, you'll have way more problems convincing people to support it than you will in preventing people from manipulating your proprietary files.  Having people write code that can interact with your files easily is generally an important driver of your file format's success.  Alienating the people you need to generate popularity for your file format would almost always be a bad idea.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying about making it an issue to deal with. But if the capability of the file format outweighed the headache I wonder if  there would be a fine line to where it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

If you define a file format, you should on the contrary **publicly document its specification**, since a file format is a mean of communicating data between software and people.

I am not the only one in **avoiding closed file formats**. If I used some of them, I would be trapped into the product needing them. *In some contexts* and many organizations, *using an undocumented proprietary file format would be frowned upon* or forbidden. In France, the Ayrault government issued a decree **favoring open standards** (and preferably free software). AFAIK the European Commission is doing something similar.

So **to be successful**, you don't want to "protect" your file format, you want to **specify your file format as well as possible in a public specification** so that it becomes a de facto standard (used by competitors).

And *you cannot legally forbid reverse-engineering your format* (at least not *in Europe* ; AFAIU reverse-engineering is explicitly legal in Europe if done for interoperability reasons, but IANAL).

Hiding your file format would probably make it a world-wide failure; nobody would use it (which of course is the ultimate protection, but are you really wanting that?).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot protect a file format legally.  However, if the process to create or use the file format is sufficiently novel, that process can potentially be patented.

For example, the .gif file format was not protected in any way shape or form.  However, the LZW algorithm used to compress or decompress gifs was assigned patents.

It mattered little until they started enforcing their patents.  The act of enforcing them turned .gif from one of the 2 mainstay image formats of the internet, into a non-starter format which is now only used because gif89a allows some rudimentary animation without a plugin.  .png has taken over the rest of the .gif market.  The patents are now all expired, but it's too late for the format.

Comment: There are continents (Europe) where algorithms cannot be patented (unless tightly tied to a *physical* device).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is interesting and good to know.  My experience with patent law is primarily US.  US law may be sufficient in many cases (esp. if your primary userbase happens to be in the US), but its' good to know there are differing positions in different parts of the globe!